# Python: problems with venv on Debian 11

Tags: python, debian

I installed Debian 11 and Python.  I'm trying to create a venv and am getting this error.  Does anyone know how to resolve it?

```
1847 [deb11:~]$ python3 -m venv ptorch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/venv/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/home/vboxuser/threading.py", line 3, in <module>
    sem = threading.Semaphore()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'threading' has no attribute 'Semaphore' (most likely due to a circular import)
```